# Railsで全てのpathに同じパラメータを付与したい

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

view,controllerの全てのpathに同じパラメータを入れたいと思いurl_optionsを使い、

```
# application_controller.rb
def url_options
  { first: "first", last: "last" }
end
```

のようにしたのですが

```
redirect_to user_path(name: "aaa")
```

ではパラメータが付与されるのに対し、

```
redirect_to user_path
```

と、引数など何も無しにした場合だけurl_optionsのパラメータが付いてくれません。
(url_options自体通らないです)
url_optionsの使い方が載っているサイトを見てもこの問題がどこにも載っていなかったのですが、
どうしたらパラメータが付与されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

RubyやRailsのバージョンなどを書いたほうが良いと思います。

目的のことを行うメソッドは`default_url_options`ではないでしょうか。

harukaさんの仰る現象は非常に古いブログエントリーなどが検索で引っかかりましたが、
Rails4.2.0で私が簡単なプログラムで試したところ`default_url_options`では
再現しないように見えました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。バージョンを書かずにすみません。Ruby2.1.2のRails4.1.0でした。url_optionsで書かれているのが多かったので今回のような状況にならないのか気になりました。default_url_optionsでいこうと思います。ありがとうございました。